# Bing maps animation translation

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime, bing-maps, pushpin

I'm using bing maps with WinRT. I want to create a translation when pushpin_click event is fired, so that it translates the current tapped pushpin in the center of my map:

```
private void Pushpin_Click(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var TappedPin = (Pushpin)sender;
     Location currentPinLocation = GetPushpinLocation(TappedPin);
     Map.Center = currentPinLocation;  //How can I make a translation animation?
}
```

Is there a way to realize that programmatically in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. You just need to get the position of the pushpin using the MapLayer class and set the view of the map like this:

```
private void Pushpin_Click(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var TappedPin = sender as Pushpin;
     Location currentPinLocation = MapLayer.GetPosition(TappedPin);
     Map.SetView(currentPinLocation);  
}
```